# Preview on multiple devices option in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uikit

I was following some tutorials on YouTube. In most tutorials they are using the UIKit (Storyboard) framework. Now watching these videos they can open multiple devices to preview the work at the same time. See the following picture:

[image]

I am using Xcode 14 and I was searching for the "Preview" option or feature they are using and I cannot find it at all. I understand that I can choose any device from the bottom and I do not think it is efficient to check each device on solo view. So how to achieve opening or previewing multiple devices like the picture above?

Answer (score 4):

Right now, my current Xcode version is ***14.3.1***. For those who want to see the Preview in the Storyboard Builder:

1. Click on the `Adjust Editor Options`

[image]

2. Click on `Assistant`

[image]

3. You can also find the `Assistant` option on top of Xcode by clicking on `Editor`. (Optional)

[image]

4. You will see a new editor added on the right with a new icon like intersecting rings.

[image]

5. Finally, go to `Editor` -> `Preview`. Or just type `command + option + Enter`

[image]

6. That's it! Now you can see the Preview and add several devices.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but all i get are huge!!! previews, and i can't find a way to zoom out...
@Flimm has found 2 ways :  
- Double-click on the empty background area to switch between 100% zoom and 50% zoom.  
- Use the pinch gesture on your trackpad. (if you have one)

Comment: Does this still work on Xcode 15 ? Id on't get the "Preview" menu on step 5, just Assistant and Layout

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 14.2, open Storyboard file viz. Main.storyboard.
Click on Editor in Menu bar and select Assistant. This should open associated ViewController.swift file.
Click on any line in the file ViewController.swift. Now, you can see the Preview option in the Editor in the Menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the keyboard shortcut
Command + Option + Enter ↩

Comment: You need to open Assistant and then press these buttons.